# how to create output box with time values using tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to a create a GUI that will display the current local time and give you a time output when you press the 'Lap' button. So far, I have create the clock and the buttons but I can't seem to figure out how to create an output box in the window that will display the timestamp when the button is pressed. I have very little programming experience so any help would be appreciated!

I have attached what I have so far:

```
import tkinter
import time
class Clock(tkinter.Label):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, seconds=True, colon=False):
        tkinter.Label.__init__(self, parent)

        self.display_seconds = seconds
        if self.display_seconds:
            self.time = time.strftime('%I:%M:%S')
        else:
            self.time = time.strftime('%I:%M %p').lstrip('0')
        self.display_time = self.time
        self.configure(text=self.display_time)

        if colon:
            self.blink_colon()

        self.after(200, self.tick)

    def tick(self):
        if self.display_seconds:
            new_time = time.strftime('%I:%M:%S')
        else:
            new_time = time.strftime('%I:%M %p').lstrip('0')
        if new_time != self.time:
            self.time = new_time
            self.display_time = self.time
            self.config(text=self.display_time)
        self.after(200, self.tick)

def timestamp():
    print(time.strftime("%I:%M:%S"))


if __name__ == "__main__":

    window = tkinter.Tk()
    frame = tkinter.Frame(window, width=800, height=800)
    frame.pack()

    tkinter.Label(frame, text="Current time: ").pack()

    clock1 = Clock(frame)
    clock1.pack()
    clock1.configure(bg='white', fg='black', font=("helvetica", 65))

    tkinter.Label(frame, text=" ").pack()

    b = tkinter.Button(frame, text='Quit', command=quit)
    b.pack(side=tkinter.RIGHT)
    b2 = tkinter.Button(frame, text='Lap', command=timestamp)
    b2.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT)

    window.mainloop()
```

I need help to create an output box in the window that will print the time when the 'Lap' button is pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `ScrolledText` and insert into it using the `insert("end", value)` command whenever the button is pressed. Here is the augmented code.

```
import tkinter
import time
from tkinter import scrolledtext
class Clock(tkinter.Label):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, seconds=True, colon=False):
        tkinter.Label.__init__(self, parent)

        self.display_seconds = seconds
        if self.display_seconds:
            self.time = time.strftime('%I:%M:%S')
        else:
            self.time = time.strftime('%I:%M %p').lstrip('0')
        self.display_time = self.time
        self.configure(text=self.display_time)

        if colon:
            self.blink_colon()

        self.after(200, self.tick)

    def tick(self):
        if self.display_seconds:
            new_time = time.strftime('%I:%M:%S')
        else:
            new_time = time.strftime('%I:%M %p').lstrip('0')
        if new_time != self.time:
            self.time = new_time
            self.display_time = self.time
            self.config(text=self.display_time)
        self.after(200, self.tick)

def timestamp():
    print(time.strftime("%I:%M:%S"))


if __name__ == "__main__":

    window = tkinter.Tk()
    frame = tkinter.Frame(window, width=800, height=800)
    frame.pack()

    tkinter.Label(frame, text="Current time: ").pack()

    text = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(frame, height=10) ##
    text.pack() ##

    clock1 = Clock(frame)
    clock1.pack()
    clock1.configure(bg='white', fg='black', font=("helvetica", 65))

    tkinter.Label(frame, text=" ").pack()

    b = tkinter.Button(frame, text='Quit', command=quit)
    b.pack(side=tkinter.RIGHT)
    b2 = tkinter.Button(frame, text='Lap', command=lambda :text.insert("end", time.strftime("%I:%M:%S")+'\n')) ##
    b2.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT)

    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you! This definitely helps. However, I was wondering if there was a way to create a box in the window that will record the timestamp each time the lap button is pressed so it creates a list of timestamps in the window that I can scroll through?

Comment: @A.ven Edited my answer. Have a look. See if it fits your description.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! This is exactly what I needed